# Why wouldn't/don't I share this? Which should it be?

Tags: usage

So I was about to write something on my Facebook wall then I find my old post then I thought about to share it so what would be right.

Instead of writing new post I thought:

> Why **wouldn't/don't** I share this.

Which one is grammatically correct I suppose *don't*, as *wouldn't* sound incorrect.

Comment: Where is the subject in your sentence??

Comment: There are no grammatical errors here in either of these examples, but they are questions, and require a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is perfectly correct, since even rhetorical questions should end in a question mark, but you're right -- "don't" is the right choice here.  ("Wouldn't" needs the context of a condition, which isn't the case here.)